# Defining a mathematical language in prolog

Tags: prolog

So I have this mathematical language, it goes like this:

```
E -> number
[+,E,E,E]  //e.g.  [+,1,2,3]  is  1+2+3 %we can put 2 to infinite Es here.
[-,E,E,E]  //e.g.  [-,1,2,3]  is  1-2-3 %we can put 2 to infinite Es here.
[*,E,E,E]  //e.g.  [*,1,2,3]  is  1*2*3 %we can put 2 to infinite Es here.
[^,E,E]    //e.g.  [^,2,3]    is  2^3
[sin,E]    //e.g.  [sin,0]    is  sin 0
[cos,E]    //e.g.  [cos,0]    is  cos 0
```

and I want to write the set of rules that finds the numeric value of a mathematical expression written by this language in prolog.

I first wrote a function called "check", it checks to see if the list is written in a right way according to the language we have :

```
check1([]).
check1([L|Ls]):- number(L),check1(Ls).
check([L|Ls]):-atom(L),check1(Ls).
```

now I need to write the function "evaluate" that takes a list that is an expression written by this language, and a variable that is the numeric value corresponding to this language.
example:

```
?-evaluate([*,1,[^,2,2],[*,2,[+,[sin,0],5]]]],N) -> N = 40
```

so I wrote this:

```
sum([],0).
sum([L|Ls],N):- not(is_list(L)),sum(Ls,No),N is No + L.
min([],0).
min([L|Ls],N):-not(is_list(L)), min(Ls,No),N is No - L.
pro([],0).
pro([X],[X]).
pro([L|Ls],N):-not(is_list(L)), pro(Ls,No), N is No * L.
pow([L|Ls],N):-not(is_list(L)), N is L ^ Ls.
sin_(L,N):-not(is_list(L)), N is sin(L).
cos_(L,N):-not(is_list(L)), N is cos(L).

d([],0).
d([L|Ls],N):- L == '+' ,sum(Ls,N);
L == '-',min(Ls,N);
L == '*',pro(Ls,N);
L == '^',pow(Ls,N);
L == 'sin',sin_(Ls,N);
L == 'cos',cos_(Ls,N).

evaluate([],0).
evaluate([L|Ls],N):-
is_list(L) , check(L) , d(L,N),L is N,evaluate(Ls,N);
is_list(L), not(check(L)) , evaluate(Ls,N);
not(is_list(L)),not(is_list(Ls)),check([L|Ls]),d([L|Ls],N),
L is N,evaluate(Ls,N);
is_list(Ls),evaluate(Ls,N).
```

and it's working for just a list and returning the right answer , but not for multiple lists inside the main list, how should my code be?

Comment: If `check(L)` fails on a list, shouldn't the entire predicate simply fail rather than attempt to evaluate an invalid list? And `not(is_list(Ls))` may not be semantically sensible since the tail of a list (`Ls` in this case) is expected always to be a list in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't organize the program this way, but given your approach, what you'd need to do is make each operator predicate recursive on a call to `d/2` and call `d/2` any time it encounters a sublist (you currently only allow `not(is_list(L))`).

Answer (score 3):

The specification you work with looks like a production rule that describes that E (presumably short for *Expression*) might be a number or one of the 6 specified operations. That is the empty list `[]` is not an expression. So the fact

```
evaluate([],0).
```

should not be in your code. Your predicate sum/2 almost works the way you wrote it, except for the empty list and a list with a single element, that are not valid inputs according to your specification. But the predicates min/2 and pro/2 are not correct. Consider the following examples:

```
   ?- sum([1,2,3],X).
X = 6                     % <- correct
   ?- sum([1],X).
X = 1                     % <- incorrect
   ?- sum([],X).
X = 0                     % <- incorrect
   ?- min([1,2,3],X).
X = -6                    % <- incorrect
   ?- pro([1,2,3],X).
X = 6 ? ;                 % <- correct
X = 0                     % <- incorrect
```

Mathematically speaking, addition and multiplication are [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) but subtraction is not. In programming languages all three of these operations are usually left associative (see e.g. [Operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)) to yield the mathematically correct result. That is, the sequence of subtractions in the above query would be calculated:

```
1-2-3 = (1-2)-3 = -4
```

The way you define a sequence of these operations resembles the following calculation:

```
[A,B,C]: ((0 op C) op B) op A
```

That works out fine for addition:

```
[1,2,3]: ((0 + 3) + 2) + 1 = 6
```

But it doesn't for subtraction:

```
[1,2,3]: ((0 - 3) - 2) - 1 = -6
```

And it is responsible for the second, incorrect solution when multiplying:

```
[1,2,3]: ((0 * 3) * 2) * 1 = 0
```

There are also some other issues with your code (see e.g. @lurker's comments), however, I won't go into further detail on that. Instead, I suggest a predicate that adheres closely to the specifying production rule. Since the grammar is describing expressions and you want to know the corresponding values, let's call it expr_val/2. Now let's describe top-down what an expression can be: It can be a number:

```
expr_val(X,X) :-
   number(X).
```

It can be an arbitrarily long sequence of additions or subtractions or multiplications respectively. For the reasons above all three sequences should be evaluated in a left associative way. So it's tempting to use one rule for all of them:

```
expr_val([Op|Es],V) :-
   sequenceoperator(Op),      % Op is one of the 3 operations
   exprseq_op_val(Es,Op,V).   % V is the result of a sequence of Ops
```

The power function is given as a list with three elements, the first being `^` and the others being expressions. So that rule is pretty straightforward:

```
expr_val([^,E1,E2],V) :-
   expr_val(E1,V1),
   expr_val(E2,V2),
   V is V1^V2.
```

The expressions for sine and cosine are both lists with two elements, the first being `sin` or `cos` and the second being an expression. Note that the argument of [sin](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=sin/1) and [cos](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=cos/1) is the angle in radians. If the second argument of the list yields the angle in radians you can use sin/1 and cos/2 as you did in your code. However, if you get the angle in degrees, you need to convert it to radians first. I include the latter case as an example, use the one that fits your application.

```
expr_val([sin,E],V) :-
   expr_val(E,V1),
   V is sin(V1*pi/180).       % radians = degrees*pi/180
expr_val([cos,E],V) :-
   expr_val(E,V1),
   V is cos(V1*pi/180).       % radians = degrees*pi/180
```

For the second rule of expr_val/2 you need to define the three possible sequence operators:

```
sequenceoperator(+).
sequenceoperator(-).
sequenceoperator(*).
```

And subsequently the predicate exprseq_op_val/3. As the leading operator has already been removed from the list in expr_val/2, the list has to have at least two elements according to your specification. In order to evaluate the sequence in a left associative way the value of the head of the list is passed as an accumulator to another predicate exprseq_op_val_/4

```
exprseq_op_val([E1,E2|Es],Op,V) :-
   expr_val(E1,V1),
   exprseq_op_val_([E2|Es],Op,V,V1).
```

that is describing the actual evaluation. There are basically two cases: If the list is empty then, regardless of the operator, the accumulator holds the result. Otherwise the list has at least one element. In that case another predicate, op_val_args/4, delivers the result of the respective operation (`Acc1`) that is then recursively passed as an accumulator to exprseq_op_val_/4 alongside with the tail of the list (`Es`):

```
exprseq_op_val_([],_Op,V,V).
exprseq_op_val_([E1|Es],Op,V,Acc0) :-
   expr_val(E1,V1),
   op_val_args(Op,Acc1,Acc0,V1),
   exprseq_op_val_(Es,Op,V,Acc1).
```

At last you have to define op_val_args/4, that is again pretty straightforward:

```
op_val_args(+,V,V1,V2) :-
   V is V1+V2.
op_val_args(-,V,V1,V2) :-
   V is V1-V2.
op_val_args(*,V,V1,V2) :-
   V is V1*V2.
```

Now let's see how this works. First your example query:

```
   ?- expr_val([*,1,[^,2,2],[*,2,[+,[sin,0],5]]],V).
V = 40.0 ? ;
no
```

The simplest expression according to your specification is a number:

```
   ?- expr_val(-3.14,V).
V = -3.14 ? ;
no
```

The empty list is not an expression:

```
   ?- expr_val([],V).
no
```

The operators `+`, `-` and `*` need at least 2 arguments:

```
   ?- expr_val([-],V).
no
   ?- expr_val([+,1],V).
no
   ?- expr_val([*,1,2],V).
V = 2 ? ;
no
   ?- expr_val([-,1,2,3],V).
V = -4 ? ;
no
```

The power function has exactly two arguments:

```
   ?- expr_val([^,1,2,3],V).
no
   ?- expr_val([^,2,3],V).
V = 8 ? ;
no
   ?- expr_val([^,2],V).
no
   ?- expr_val([^],V).
no
```

And so on...